Open Subsets of a Paracompact space
So in general it seems that open subsets of paracompact spaces are not paracompact. Does anyone have a concrete example?
Furthermore does anyone know conditions for when open subsets of a paracompact space are paracompact. I know for example metrisability is sufficient however i was hoping some weaker conditions would suffice, for example Hausdorff and locally compact.

At least in $T_2$-spaces, the following holds:
(1) a space is hereditarily paracompact (= each subset is paracompact), iff each open subset is paracompact.
(2) each $F_\sigma$ subset of a paracompact space is paracompact.
Hence: a perfect (= open subsets are $F_\sigma$), $T_2$ paracompact is hereditarily paracompact.
The Sorgenfrey line is an example of a perfect,$T_2$ paracompact space, which is not metrisable.

@Ulli thanks! do you have references for the statements? Also do you know of some conditions for a space to be perfect in terms of local compactness plus some other properties for example?

(1) is Exercise 5.1.F.(a) in Engelking, General Topology, (2) is Theorem 5.1.28 in Engelking. Local compactness and perfectness are so unrelated properties, that presumably there is nothing related to your second question. Also note that local compactness is a local property, whereas paracompactness or perfectness are global properties.

For your first question, take any non-paracompact space that is locally compact Hausdorff (say, the long line). Then it is an open subset of its one-point compactification, which is compact and thus of course also paracompact. This, of course, also tells you that, for your second question, even assuming the larger space is compact and Hausdorff is not enough to guarantee the result you want.

Assuming second-countability and Hausdorff condition would be enough - but that would imply metrizability, since any second-countable Hausdorff paracompact space is metrizable.
